# I want to hide some nav menu items in the joomla admin template "isis"

Tags: php, html, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I want to remove the some links or hide them in the joomla admin template. These links are in the nav-menu of template "isis". For example, in the nav-menu of admin area go to, components > joomjob freelance, now from the sub menus, I want to remove links of my choice say Escrow, Summary, Subscriptions.

I can make this more clear through image but don't have reputation to post one.

I know this can be done through css but I want to do it through backend programming. Does anyone have an idea where can I access the programming or stop these items or any other items of my choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in the #__menu table in phpMyAdmin by deleting the items that you do not want to display. Note that these items will no longer display for anyone, but their links will be still valid (so if someone knows the link, then he'll be able to access the page).

Comment: Thanks man. That was very helpful. Can you tell me where can I find the html for email templates. I want to display title eg."Subscription" and subtitle eg, "Pending Subscriptions" altogether on the "Email Templates" page. It currently shows just the subtitle.. Where can I find the root for the html that is generated dynamically to create this ?

Comment: Hi Muddassir, would you please create another question with your request? This will be more helpful for others with the same question.